# Tinymce did not initialized in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce, tinymce-4

I've integrated tinymce, but have a trouble with IE. 
tinymce initializes in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc. , but nothing happens in IE.
When rendering, textarea appeared, then went hidden and that's all.

```
tinymce.init({
   //settings
}).then(function(editors) {
   //...
});
```

`init` should return `Promise`, but `then` is not being fired. 
The same is about `init_instance_callback`, `setup` placed in initialization.

I have got the same problems with the `tinymce.EditorManager.init({...})` .
As a result there is not any editor in the tinymce. Maybe tinymce even didn't get initialized. I am using v4.3.12 of tinymce.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Are there errors in the browser's JavaScript console?  What if you just remove the `.then...` portion of the init?  Does IE work?  What version of IE are you trying to use?

Comment: There is an error as it cannot call setContent on the undefined, but there is not any error about initialization itself. If I remove `.then`, I should use `tinymce.EditorManager.init(...)`, this is said in their documentation. Here it is https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#init. I am using IE 11.